# Import large CSV file with utf-8(Chinese chars) contents in Python 3.5

Tags: python, csv, utf-8

First of all, I know there is a standard way of doing the task I state in the title. For example,

```python
import csv
with open('test.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

I apply this code on my data file(~262MB) in a Jupyter terminal, I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-cbed80c58499> in <module>()
      2 with open('CarRecord.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
      3     reader = csv.reader(f)
----> 4     for row in reader:
      5         print(row)

//anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    319         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    320         data = self.buffer + input
--> 321         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    322         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    323         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa9 in position 74: invalid start byte
```

Okay, position 74 is at the first row of my data file, where the first Chinese char. comes up. So I do another quick test, which I copy the first few rows from my data file and paste them into another new file. I run the same code with the test file, and now it just works as normal as I would expect, without any error messages.

Anyone has any ideas, please?....

------updated following the ideas in the comment:-------

```python
import csv
with open('CarRecord.txt', mode='rb') as f:
    decoded_file = f.read().decode('utf-16')
    reader = csv.reader(decoded_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

now I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-3708b52ef0a3> in <module>()
      1 import csv
      2 with open('CarRecord.txt', mode='rb') as f:
----> 3     decoded_file = f.read().decode('utf-16')
      4     reader = csv.reader(decoded_file, delimiter=',')
      5     for row in reader:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 1780-1781: illegal UTF-16 surrogate
```

Comment: Have you tested the `utf-16` instead of `utf-8`?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 1780-1781: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Comment: It seems that you have some separate bytes in your file, you can read the file in binary mode and then decode the file with `utf-16` encoding.

Comment: open('CarRecord.txt', mode='rb', encoding='utf-16')    ----  this gives me "ValueError: binary mode doesn't take an encoding argument"

Comment: open('CarRecord.txt', mode='rb') ---- this gives me "Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)"

Comment: Don't pass the file object to `csv.reader()` before decoding. Do  `decoded_file = f.read().decode('utf-16')` then `csv.reader(decoded_file, delimiter=your_delimiter)`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but maybe I still did it wrong...I will put the code I used following your idea in the updates above...

Comment: You can try to ignore the errors- if those characters are not important or are damaged by passing the `ignore` or `replace` to `decode` attribute. `f.read().decode('utf-16', 'ignore')`. Read more here https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: Tried to use 'ignore', but then the .decode() seems to try to decode everything into utf-16---even for those letters and numbers....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a precise answer to the question.

It turns out that the original data file -- although it contains unicode characters -- was encoded with ASCII. So I save a new data file and encode it with utf-8, and the standard method of reading CSV file just worked.